# Changes are not reflecting in the UI after updating the state in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

. I'm trying to sort the data by name and age when clicked on the header of the column. Data is getting sorted but not reflecting in the UI.
I'm sharing the code snippet,
Someone please help me out

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([{ name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Mary', age: 31 }, { name: 'Anna', age: 18 }, { name: 'Mark', age: 21 }])
  function sort(sortBy) {
    if (sortBy == 'name') {
      names.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name > b.name)
          return 1
        else return -1
      })
      setNames(names)
    } else if (sortBy == 'age') {
      names.sort((a, b) => { return b.age - a.age })
      setNames(names)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th><span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => { sort('name') }}>Name</span></th>
          <th><span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => { sort('age') }}>Age</span></th>
        </tr>
        {names.map((data) => {
          return (<tr>
            <td> {data.name}  </td>
            <td> {data.age}  </td>
          </tr>)
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: FYI: You will only ever sort in on direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly modifying the `names` state variable, therefore React is not able to update the state since the reference to the array is going to be the same. Instead of directly modifying the `names` array, create a new array when updating the state variable

```
function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([{ name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Mary', age: 31 }, { name: 'Anna', age: 18 }, { name: 'Mark', age: 21 }])
  function sort(sortBy) {
    if (sortBy == 'name') {
      names.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name > b.name)
          return 1
        else return -1
      })
      setNames([...names]) // new array
    } else if (sortBy == 'age') {
      names.sort((a, b) => { return b.age - a.age })
      setNames([...names]) // new array
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th><span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => { sort('name') }}>Name</span></th>
          <th><span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => { sort('age') }}>Age</span></th>
        </tr>
        {names.map((data) => {
          return (<tr>
            <td> {data.name}  </td>
            <td> {data.age}  </td>
          </tr>)
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing one mistake here . Which is  :

In React, the state is immutable. In simple words it means that you should not modify it directly.

**Explanation :**

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([])

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  arr.push("New Item")
  setArr(arr)
}
```

**Why Above code didn't work in push ?**

React determines whether the component needs to be re-rendered by comparing the prior state with the updated state. Directly changing the state will interfere with this procedure. The component will behave unexpectedly as a result. In other instances, even when the state has changed, rendering is not performed at all.

So this can be solved as :

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([
    { name: 'John', age: 23 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 31 },
    { name: 'Anna', age: 18 },
    { name: 'Mark', age: 21 }
  ]);

  function sort(sortBy) {
    if (sortBy === 'name') {
      const sortedNames = [...names].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      });
      setNames(sortedNames);
    } else if (sortBy === 'age') {
      const sortedNames = [...names].sort((a, b) => b.age - a.age);
      setNames(sortedNames);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => sort('name')}>
                Name
              </span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => sort('age')}>
                Age
              </span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {names.map((data, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.age}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The spread syntax creates a copy of the array. Hence we are not modifying the original array.

Hope this works properly. If you have any problem let me know.